# Audit log and Vault Hashicorp cluster

Tags: hashicorp-vault

I'm trying to enable audit in my 3 nodes Vault cluster (no enterprise version).

From official documentation we have:

```
vault audit enable file file_path=/var/log/vault_audit.log
```

> Audit device configuration is replicated to all nodes within a cluster
> by default, and to performance/DR secondaries for Vault Enterprise
> clusters.

So if I wish to enable audit, let's say in path : /var/log/vault_audit.log.

Do I need to enter this command on each of my nodes or only one?

Does each node write their audit log on the same /var/log/vault_audit.log ( to the node where audit was activated) or does each node will write audit log in their own virtual machine (so I will have multiple /var/log/vault_audit.log)?

Answer (score 0):

You enable the audit log on the "leader" node.  The rest of the nodes in the same cluster are performance standbys and will copy the from the leader.
Note, you can add a -local parameter to localize the config to the cluster you're on.  This is only a requirement if you have an enterprise license and planning to build a performance replica cluster.

Comment: thats not my observation inside my vault HA setup (2 nodes, no enterprice license needed - https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/docs/concepts/ha) - When one node is down the logs are written on the other node, even if the first node is reachable again. Unfortunately nothing is copied between the audit-logs. I have vaultnode01:/var/log/vault_audit.log and vaultnode02:/var/log/vault_audit.log both with *different* content. Unfort. I cant find information how to streamline this behavior. Everything seems to work, so that good, but it's not clear

Comment: @MacMartin that's exactly the scenario I described above so not sure what you're observing that is different.  A cluster consists of multiple nodes (1,3+) [btw it should be an odd number of nodes for a healthy cluster].  The configuration is done at the cluster level, the leader node will do 99% of the logging -- until that node is no longer the active node, when one of the other nodes becomes the active node that node will log what it sees.

Comment: thx for your reply @awm. Maybe I misunderstood. when you wrote "...and will copy the from the leader." I thought you meant, that the logfile contents will be copied to the "secondary" node when it is working normal, and after a potential failover is resolved, contents are copied to the leading node when it becomes available again (this doesn't happen in my environment). 
Strangely, even if the leading node becomes availabe again, logging still happens on the "secondaries" until  the process gets the HUP signal. Do you know how to control that or have a hint or link to information/docs?

Comment: @MacMartin That's a very rare situation that a leader instance would lose it's leader flag, and then gain it back.  The only time I have seen it is when I have forced it. This is assuming not kubernetes as those things are a whole other beast that cannot be explained by the human knowledge. Do make sure you're running a later version if not the latest, a lot of improvements have been implemented that I can see in the stability of the cluster.  We also just moved over to Integrated Storage which is great.